# Downloading .cer file from Webview

Tags: android, webview

I am wondering since 2 days but not be able to fix it.

I have a URL opened inside on `WebView`.
there is one `Button` in website which to download a **.cer** file .

My problem is when i click on that `Button` it starts to download file and notified me in `Notification Bar`.

I am trying below code to do this:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(sourceURL));
// appears the same in Notification bar while downloading

request.setTitle("Downloading");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
}
//DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);                        
manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
// Use the same file name for the destination
File destinationFile = new File(directory, "/Download/test.cer");

if (destinationFile.exists()) {
    destinationFile.delete();
}
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(destinationFile));
// Add it to the manager
referencepath = manager.enqueue(request);
```

the same is happening with default browser of Device but i am able to downloading file when
i open the url in firefox browser.

i have also added permissions

```
<!-- Permission so that application can access Internet -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<!-- Permission so that application can write on device storage -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in Manifest file.

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally I succeeded to download .cer file.

The code which worked for me is as:

```
String sourceURL = url;
        String directoryPath = directoryPath;
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(sourceURL);
        try {

            /**
             * getting Session Id from URL which is in Webview
             */
            String sessionId = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(
                    sourceURL.toString());
            if (sessionId != null)
                httpPost.addHeader("Cookie", sessionId);
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpPost);
            String certResponseBody = EntityUtils.toString(execute
                    .getEntity());
```

and I got my .cer file as a string in certResponseBody which I saved as a .cer file in device storage.

Cheers....